# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when attempting to write out to CSV in python

Tags: python, string, csv, dictionary

I am using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.4. I have a data structure in the format:

```
[{'AccountNumber': N,
'Amount': '0',
 'Answer': '12:00:00 PM',
  'ID': None,
  'Type': 'WriteLetters',
  'Amount': '10',
  {'AccountNumber': Y,
      'Amount': '0',
      'Answer': ' 12:00:00 PM',       
       'ID': None,
      'Type': 'Transfer',
      'Amount': '2'}]
```

The end goal is to write this out to CSV.

For the above example the output would look like:

```
AccountNumber, Amount, Answer, ID, Type, Amount
N,0,12:00:00 PM,None,WriteLetters,10
Y,2,12:00:00 PM,None,Transfer,2
```

Below is the function that I am using to write out this data structure. Please excuse any indentation formatting issues. The data structure is returned through the function `construct_results(get_just_xml_data)`. The data that is returned is in the format as above. `construct_headers(get_just_xml_data)` returns a list of headers. Writing out the row for `headers_list` works.

The list comprehension `data` is to remove duplicates and maintain the integrity of the column headers and the values for each new instance of the data structure (where the keys in the dictionary are the headers and values - row instances). The keys in this specific data structure are meant to check if there is a value instance, and if there is not - place an `''`.

```
def write_to_csv(results, headers):

    headers = construct_headers(get_just_xml_data)
    results = construct_results(get_just_xml_data)
    headers_list = list(headers)

    with open('real_csv_output.csv', 'wt') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers_list)
        for row in results:
            data = [row.get(index, '') for index in results]
        writer.writerow(data)
```

However, when I run this, I receive this error:

```
The end goal is to write this out to CSV.
```

For the above example the output would look like:

```
AccountNumber, Amount, Answer, ID, Type, Amount
N,0,12:00:00 PM,None,WriteLetters,10
Y,2,12:00:00 PM,None,Transfer,2

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-744-7746797fc9a5> in <module>()
----> 1 write_to_csv(results, headers)

<ipython-input-743-c822437eeaf0> in write_to_csv(results, headers)
      9         writer.writerow(headers_list)
     10         for item in results:
---> 11             data = [item.get(index, '') for index in results]
     12         writer.writerow(data)

<ipython-input-743-c822437eeaf0> in <listcomp>(.0)
      9         writer.writerow(headers_list)
     10         for item in results:
---> 11             data = [item.get(index, '') for index in results]
     12         writer.writerow(data)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I welcome any feedback on what may be the cause.

Comment: Where are you defining `row`?  Is there something at the global level with it, because there doesn't seem to be a place in the code you provide where you define it, but it's part of the error you're seeing

Comment: @EricRenouf Made the changes

Comment: @EricRenouf I receive a different error when I run this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the drawing board:

These are my findings:

The ‘`for`’ statement iterates over ‘`results`’, getting an item each time. 
The name ‘row’ is bound to each item in turn.

Then, each time through the ‘`for`’ loop, I iterate ***again*** over 
‘`results`’. The name ‘`index`’ is bound to each item.

I then attempt to use the dict (each item from ‘`results`’ is itself a 
dict) as a key into that same dict. A dict is not a valid key; it is not 
a “hashable type” i.e. a type with a fixed value, that can produce a 
hash of the value).

So I was getting dicts and attempting to use those dicts as keys into 
dicts. That will give the error `“TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'”.`

I wanted not the items from the original sequence, but the 
keys from the mapping::

```
for input_record in results: 
    output_record = [input_record.get(key, "") for key in input_record]
```

But I've then throwing away the constructed list, since I do nothing 
with it before the end of the loop.

```
     `writer.writerow(data)`
```

This statement occurs only ***after*** all the items from ‘**results**’ have 
been iterated. You will only have the most recent constructed row.

I wanted the following:

```
   for input_record in results: 
        output_record = [input_record.get(key, "") for key in input_record] 
        writer.writerow(output_record)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv.DictWriter()` to do this a little more easily:

```
with open('real_csv_output.csv', 'wt') as f:
    csvw = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=results[0].keys())
    csvw.writeheader()
    csvw.writerows(results)
```

BTW the error you are getting is because `row` is a string... You probably meant `item.get()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the catching that. I am going to try your suggestion and get back to you. Thanks.